# Алгоритм поиска минимального количества ходов, требуемых для приведения всех элементов к одному числу (Python)

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, list, циклы

Прошу помочь решить задачу или хотя бы намекнуть, в какую сторону "копать".
Дан массив целых чисел. Необходимо найти минимальное количество ходов, требуемых для приведения всех элементов массива к одному числу. За один ход можно уменьшить или увеличить один элемент массива на 1.
Все достаточно просто пока массив выглядит вот так:

```
`
import math


nums = [1, 10, 2, 9]
result_digit = math.ceil((max(nums))/2)
count = 0
for id, i in enumerate(nums):
    while i != result_digit:
        if i < result_digit:
            i += 1
            count += 1
         elif i > result_digit:
             i -= 1
             count += 1
         else:
            nums[id] = i
    print(count)
`
```

Но, если nums = [0, 0, 0, 1], тогда этот алгоритм не подходит и выведет результат 3 вместо 1.
Массив может быть любой длинны.

Comment: Не к медиане ли надо приводить?

Answer (score 3):

Посмотрим на задачу с конца. Если мы как-то узнали значение `m` к которому нужно привести массив, то сколько на это уйдет шагов? Для одного элемента массива `a[i]` потребуется `abs(a[i] - m)` шагов. Для всего массива `sum(abs(v - m) for v in a)`.

Известно что минимум суммы выше будет достигаться если `m` [медиана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) `a`. Медиан может быть много. Одна из медиан - средний элемент массива после его сортировки.

```
a = [1, 10, 2, 9]
m = sorted(a)[len(a) // 2]
print(sum(abs(v - m) for v in a))
```

> ```
> 16
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых округлять нужно с помощью `round`, у вас получается не оптимальное округление, не к ближайшему целому. А во-вторых - почему `max/2`? Приводить нужно к среднему арифметическому:

```
result_digit = round(sum(nums)/len(nums))
```

Можете проверить на примере, где все числа далеки от нуля. Ваш вариант начнёт приводить куда-то вообще не туда. Например, если взять:

```
nums = [9, 9, 9, 10]
```

Ваш вариант начнёт приводить всё к `10/2`, т.е. `5`, а не к округлённому среднему `9`, как было бы оптимально.

Comment: Ваш алгоритм не работает для массива [3, 3, 1]. Среднее округленное = 2, но оптимальней всего привести этот массив к массиву троек.

Comment: @Zergatul Ну тогда может медиану нужно выбирать )